# jQuery: Listener to input attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<textarea id="test" disabled>Test</textarea>
```

Is there a way to listen to the changes in the attributes? such as `disabled` attribute.

I need an event to add or remove "disabled" attr. Something like this:

```js
$("#test").on("change attribute",function(){
    alert("Textarea enabled");
})
```

Comment: Yes, look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a MutationObserver:

```js
console.log('script start');
const test = document.querySelector('#test');

new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'disabled') {
      console.log('Change detected');
    }
  }
})
  .observe(test, { attributes: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  test.removeAttribute('disabled');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<textarea id="test" disabled>Test</textarea>
```

No external libraries like jQuery needed; this is supported in essentially all browsers nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am testing it

Comment: That was perfect.